# Convert rgb values to one hot labels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I got an RGB image

```
 img= np.array(Image.open(path, dtype=np.uint8))
```

with 3 unique labels:

```
 labels = list(np.unique(img.reshape(-1, img.shape[2]), axis=0))
 
labels =

[array([  0,   0, 255...ype=uint8), array([255,   0, 255...ype=uint8), array([255, 255, 255...ype=uint8)]
```

I want to write some code to convert the RGB values to one hot labels, e.g:

```
[0,0,255] -> [0,0,1] , [255,0,255] -> [1,0,0],  [255,255,255] -> [0,1,0].
```

I tried:

```
    for i in range(len(labels)):
      label = labels[i]
      layout[img==label] = i
```

But can't even index the cells, since I got:

```
NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 233357 output values where the mask is true
```

Comment: What is 'layout'?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a native english speaker and it is difficult for me to understand when you don't use complete sentences. I would like to help you though. would you kindly rephrase the last sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming `layout` is the variable where you want to store the modified i.e., *one-hot encoded* image and `img` is the original image or numpy array having shape *M x N x 3*.

```py
labels_old = [[0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 255],  [255, 255, 255]]
labels_new = [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]

layout = img.copy()
for i, label in enumerate(labels_old):
    layout[np.all(img == label, axis = -1)] = labels_new[i]
```